# How to redirect to a route in laravel 5 by using href tag if I'm not using blade or any template?

Tags: redirect, routes, laravel-5, href

```
Route::get('/page','UserController@view page');
```

is my route.

I have a list with href tag and I want to redirect to this route.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="">how it works</a></li>
</ul>
```

I am not using blade or any other templates.

Comment: Just add the path within the `href` attribute. `<li><a href="/page">how it works</a></li>`

Comment: it redirects to `localhost/page`.

Comment: What is the expected URL.

Comment: Without using laravels URL functions  its tricky to point to that URL and impractical as when you are moving to production you will need to point to serve requests from public directory. So for development either you can use virtual hosts or laravel URL function after configuring app URL in config

Comment: `localhost/example/public/page`

Comment: so..? what i wanna change in that config app.php file..? i can see the line like this `'url' => 'http://localhost'`

Comment: See the added answer.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

In you app config file change the `url` to `localhost/example/public`

Then when you want to link to something

`<a href="{{ url('page') }}">Some Text</a>`

without blade

`<a href="<?php echo url('page') ?>">Some Text</a>`

Answer (score 27):

In addition to @chanafdo answer, you can use route name

#### when working with laravel blade

`<a href="{{route('login')}}">login here</a>`

with parameter in route name

when go to url like URI: profile/{id}

`<a href="{{route('profile', ['id' => 1])}}">login here</a>`

#### without blade

`<a href="<?php echo route('login')?>">login here</a>`

with parameter in route name

when go to url like URI: profile/{id}

`<a href="<?php echo route('profile', ['id' => 1])?>">login here</a>`

As of laravel 5.2 you can `use @php @endphp` to create as `<?php ?>` in laravel blade. 
Using blade your personal opinion but I suggest to use it. Learn it.
It has many wonderful features as [template inheritance](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#template-inheritance), [Components & Slots](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#components-and-slots),[subviews](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#rendering-views-for-collections) etc...

Comment: you need to name your route ```Route::get('profile/{id}', 'somecontroller@somefunction')->name('profile');```

Answer (score 2):

Please consider this solution whith laravel blade for edit an item from list

```
            <a href="{{ url('players' , [ 'id' => $player->id ]) }}/edit"
               class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Varia</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
```